# how to open PDF file from server with native application in winRT?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

i am working on WinRT C# app. i have one url say "http://www.example.com/test.pdf". can i open this in app with native pdf aaplication of winRT?

Comment: FYI, in Windows8, default pdf reader app called "Reader" is installed. So, if you write Launcher code as below answer, Reader app will be opened.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Launcher.LanuchUriAsync` will do this for you. You can refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh701484.aspx) for more info on it, but the following should do the trick:-

```
// The URI to launch
string uriToLaunch = @"http://www.example.com/test.pdf";
var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);

async void DefaultLaunch()
{
   // Launch the URI with a warning prompt
   var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);    
}
```